# Add underscore as a separator in a binary number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, numbers, separator

I a trying to convert a decimal number into a 17-bit binary number and add underscore as a separator in it.
I am using the following code -

```
id = 18
get_bin = lambda x, n: format(x, 'b').zfill(n)
bin_num = get_bin(id, 17)
```

The output I am getting is in the form of -

```
00000000000010010
```

I am trying to get the following output -

```
0_0000_0000_0001_0010
```

How can I get it?

Comment: What output do you expect to see for `get_bin(id, 16)` and `get_bin(id, 4)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
import textwrap
result = '_'.join(textwrap.wrap(bin_num[::-1], 4))[::-1]
```

##### output:

```
'0_0000_0000_0001_0010'
```

Comment: isn't importing a module to do it an overkill?

Comment: @anurag that's why I added it's `One way` to solve the problem!!. As I know there are other better ways.

Answer (score 9):

Using good'ol pal, Python's [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

```
id = 18
width = 17
bin_num = format(id, '0{}_b'.format(width+3))
print(bin_num)
#0_0000_0000_0001_0010
```

Comment: there seems to be some bug here.  width 18 makes the same output.  +1 anyway ..

Comment: @wim, good catch, now I am scratching my head over it! I went with the first configuration that gave desired result, but, now I want to know why this problem!

Comment: It’s because the _width_ parameter of an f-string (or `format` in this case) weirdly includes the underscore character into account. In this case, your _effective width_ of `width + 3` is `20` is not enough to hold the whole string: `17 digits + 4 underscores = 21`. So python ignores the _effective width_ and produces the 21 character string sufficient to hold the entire number requested. This is why `width = 18` also produced the same result: _effective width_ of `18+3` is `21` which is just enough to fit the string including the underscores. See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using f-strings should do it but notice the documentation for *width* [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> *width* is a decimal integer defining the minimum total field width, **including any prefixes, separators, and other formatting characters.** ...

(emphasis mine)

So you need to modify the "width" variable by the number of underscores you expect to have in the string. Let's look at the underscore documentation in that same page:

> The `'_'` option signals the use of an underscore for a thousands separator for floating point presentation types and for integer presentation type `'d'`. **For integer presentation types `'b'`, `'o'`, `'x'`, and `'X'`, underscores will be inserted every 4 digits.**

So we need to increment "width" by one character for every underscore we expect to see in the final string.

Here's my solution:

```py
def get_bin_string(number, width):
    # f"{number:{width}b}" is the number in binary format with a minimum of "width" bits
    # len(...) is the actual width of the number in case "width" is too small
    # ...-1 is to correct a one-off error
    # .../4 is to get the number of underscores we'll need
    # int(...) is to round down to an integer value
    num_underscores = int((len(f"{number:{width}b}")-1)/4)

    # get the final string we want now including the underscores
    # The '0' to the right of the "":" is to pad the extra bits with 0
    return f"{number:0{width + num_underscores}_b}"


num = 18
width = 17

print(get_bin_string(num, width))

width = 18
print(get_bin_string(num, width))
```

Output:

```bash
0_0000_0000_0001_0010
00_0000_0000_0001_0010
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the _ to the format string, and also you don't need to use zfill - 017_b formats to a minimum length of 17 characters, zero filling the space, and using _ in between.

```
print(format(18, '021_b'))
```

gives

```
0_0000_0000_0001_0010
```

Also note in binary mode, the underscores are always every 4 digits as you require there.
[More](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: Your comment says 17b but your code says 21b. FWIW, that’s because 17 characters plus 4 underscores is 21 characters total. See my solution for a complete answer that works for more than just width 17